# Why is Postman sending an empty request while browser sends a legitimate request?

Tags: java, http, get, postman, network-programming

I have been writing an HTTP handler in Java and earlier, I was able to process Postman requests but now they are received empty (still seen by the code because it creates an object but it is empty. I have a logger to print out the request and these are the results for browser request and Postman request:
Browser request:

```
                                           Server started.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Port in use: 8080
Request Line METHOD to process: GET
Request Line REQUEST TARGET to process: /
Request Line HTTP VERSION to process: HTTP/1.1
Header added: Host:  localhost:8080
Header added: Connection:  keep-alive
Header added: sec-ch-ua:  "Not/A)Brand";v="99", "Brave";v="115", "Chromium";v="115"
Header added: sec-ch-ua-mobile:  ?0
Header added: sec-ch-ua-platform:  "Windows"
Header added: Upgrade-Insecure-Requests:  1
Header added: User-Agent:  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/115.0.0.0 Safari/537.36
Header added: Accept:  text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/avif,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Header added: Sec-GPC:  1
Header added: Accept-Language:  en-US,en
Header added: Sec-Fetch-Site:  none
Header added: Sec-Fetch-Mode:  navigate
Header added: Sec-Fetch-User:  ?1
Header added: Sec-Fetch-Dest:  document
Header added: Accept-Encoding:  gzip, deflate, br
com.project.HTTP.Requests.HttpRequest@2cea1072
```

Postman Request:

```
                                           Server started.
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Port in use: 8080
com.project.HTTP.Requests.HttpRequest@3e385b97
Exception in thread "Thread-0" java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke "com.project.HTTP.HttpMethod.toString()" because the return value of "com.project.HTTP.Requests.HttpRequest.getMethod()" is null
    at com.project.HTTP.Util.HttpResponseGenerator.generateResponse(HttpResponseGenerator.java:18)
    at com.project.HTTP.server.ServerListernerThread.run(ServerListernerThread.java:37)
```

This is a demo project and there is no sensitive information so I can provide you the code but I don't think the problem is caused by the code because the browser request can be processed completely fine. So I thought the problem might be caused by Postman. Here is how the postman request looks like:

Postman Request
[image]

Note that I was able to receive a proper Postman request and print it to the console earlier. I didn't change the code after that but added other classes for generating responses and connecting to database. I think these are not relevant because the exception is thrown before any instance of these classes are created. Also the exception is rightfully thrown because the request is obviously empty according to the loggers.

I have tried writing the Host header myself thinking maybe the request is not send, but later discovered this is not the case since the socket is listened until a request is made and then proceeds with that request - which is an empty input string.

Please ask if any additional information is required. Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm sharing the related code to make it clearer:

Server Class:

```
package com.project.HTTP.server;

import java.io.IOException;

public class Server {
    
                                                                    //              -- CONFIGURATION --             //
    final static private int PORT = 8080;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("                                           Server started.\n-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Port in use: " + Integer.toString(PORT));
        try {
            ServerListernerThread thread = new ServerListernerThread(PORT);
            thread.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("An error has occured: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }

}
```

Thread Class:

```
package com.project.HTTP.server;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;

import com.project.HTTP.HttpParser;
import com.project.HTTP.HttpParsingException;
import com.project.HTTP.Requests.HttpRequest;
import com.project.HTTP.Responses.HttpResponse;
import com.project.HTTP.Util.HttpResponseGenerator;

public class ServerListernerThread extends Thread {
    
    private int port;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;


    public ServerListernerThread(int port) throws IOException {
        this.port = port;
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
        
    }
    
    public void run() {
        while (!serverSocket.isClosed() && serverSocket.isBound()) {
            Socket socket = null;
            try {
                socket = serverSocket.accept();
                InputStream inputStream = socket.getInputStream();
                int _byte;
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
                HttpRequest request = HttpParser.parseHttpRequest(inputStream);
                HttpResponse response = HttpResponseGenerator.generateResponse(request);
                System.out.println(response);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (HttpParsingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (!(socket == null)) {
                    try {
                        socket.close();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

HttpParser Class:

```
package com.project.HTTP;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Map;

import com.project.HTTP.Requests.HttpRequest;
import com.project.HTTP.Responses.HttpResponse;

public class HttpParser {

    private static final int SP = 0x20; // 32
    private static final int CR = 0x0D; // 13
    private static final int LF = 0x0A; // 10
    private static final int COLON = 0x3A; // 58

    public static HttpRequest parseHttpRequest(InputStream inputStream) throws HttpParsingException, IOException {
        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
        /*                                                                                              ↑   ---DOC---  ↑
         *  Instead of using inputStream directly, we are using an InputStreamReader, which converts the array of bytes
         *  into an array of chars. This way we can work on it easier without converting every single time.
         */
        HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();


            parseRequestLine(reader, request);
            parseRequestHeaders(reader, request);
            parseRequestBody(reader, request);
            System.out.println(request);
        return request;
    }

    private static void parseRequestLine(InputStreamReader reader, HttpRequest httpRequest)
            throws IOException, HttpParsingException {

        boolean methodParsed = false;
        boolean requestTargetParsed = false;

        int _byte;
        StringBuilder processingDataBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        while ((_byte = reader.read()) >= 0) {
            if (_byte == CR) {
                _byte = reader.read();
                if (_byte == LF) {
                    httpRequest.setHttpVersion(processingDataBuffer.toString());
                    System.out.println("Request Line HTTP VERSION to process: " + httpRequest.getHttpVersion());
                    if (!methodParsed || !requestTargetParsed) {
                        throw new HttpParsingException(HttpStatusCode.CLIENT_ERROR_400_BAD_REQUEST);
                        // Ending up here would mean that either Method or ReqTarget is missing in the request.
                    }
                    return;
                } else {
                    throw new HttpParsingException(HttpStatusCode.CLIENT_ERROR_400_BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }
            if (_byte == SP) {
                if (!methodParsed) {
                    httpRequest.setMethod(processingDataBuffer.toString());
                    System.out.println("Request Line METHOD to process: " + httpRequest.getMethod().toString());
                    methodParsed = true;
                } else if (!requestTargetParsed) {
                    httpRequest.setRequestTarget(processingDataBuffer.toString());
                    System.out.println("Request Line REQUEST TARGET to process: " + httpRequest.getRequestTarget());
                    requestTargetParsed = true;
                } else {
                    throw new HttpParsingException(HttpStatusCode.CLIENT_ERROR_400_BAD_REQUEST);
                }
                processingDataBuffer.delete(0, processingDataBuffer.length());
            } else {
                processingDataBuffer.append((char) _byte);
                if (!methodParsed) {
                    if (processingDataBuffer.length() > HttpMethod.MAX_LENGTH) {
                        throw new HttpParsingException(HttpStatusCode.SERVER_ERROR_501_METHOD_NOT_IMPLEMENTED);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private static void parseRequestHeaders(InputStreamReader reader, HttpRequest httpRequest) 
            throws IOException, HttpParsingException {
        
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        StringBuilder headerNameBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder headerValueBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        boolean state = false; // false: parsing name; true: parsing value
        boolean CrlfChecker = false;

        int _byte;
        while ((_byte = reader.read()) >= 0) {
            if (_byte == CR) {
                _byte = reader.read();
                if (_byte == LF) {
                    if (headerNameBuffer.length() > 0 && headerValueBuffer.length() > 0) {
                        headers.addHeader(headerNameBuffer.toString().trim(), headerValueBuffer.toString().trim());
                        System.out.println(
                                "Header added: " + headerNameBuffer.toString() + ": " + headerValueBuffer.toString());
                        headerNameBuffer.delete(0, headerNameBuffer.length());
                        headerValueBuffer.delete(0, headerValueBuffer.length());
                        CrlfChecker = true;
                        state = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    throw new HttpParsingException(HttpStatusCode.CLIENT_ERROR_400_BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            }
            // The ifs above mean the pointer is at the end of a header line and it is parsed.
            // Following the else if below means that it is not yet the end of a header line and there is still chars to be parsed before moving to the next step in the loop.
            else
            if (!state) { // parsing header name
                CrlfChecker = false; // Resetting CrlfChecker since the last char wasn't LF.
                if (_byte == COLON) {
                    state = true; // Switch to Parsing Header Value
                } else {
                    headerNameBuffer.append((char) _byte);
                }

            } else { // parsing header value
                CrlfChecker = false; // Resetting CrlfChecker since the last char wasn't LF.
                headerValueBuffer.append((char) _byte);
            }
        }
        httpRequest.setHttpHeaders(headers);
    }

    private static void parseRequestBody(InputStreamReader reader, HttpRequest httpRequest)
            throws IOException {
        
        StringBuilder processingDataBuffer = new StringBuilder();
        int _byte;
        while ((_byte = reader.read()) >= 0) {
            processingDataBuffer.append((char) _byte);
            httpRequest.setBody(processingDataBuffer.toString());
            System.out.println("Body parsed as following: " + httpRequest.getBody());
            
        }
    }

    public static void parseHttpResponse(HttpResponse response,OutputStream outputStream) throws IOException {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : response.getHeaders().getAllHeaders().entrySet()) {
            sb.append(entry.getKey() + ": " + entry.getValue() + "\r\n");
        }
        String headers = sb.toString();
        String responseText = response.getHttpVersion() + " " + response.getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusMessage() + "\r\n" +
                "Content-Type: application/json\r\n" +
                headers + "\r\n" +
                response.getBody();
        
        outputStream.write(responseText.getBytes());
        System.out.println("LOG ENTRY: Response sent.");
    }
}
```

Parser class is where the error is detected but I realised the inputStream from the ServerListenerThread class is returned empty so the error first occurs there.

Comment: *I don't think the problem is caused by the code* - yeah right.

Comment: did you try debugging the request? See where the NPE is coming from?

Comment: @MissSkooterstandswPalestine I did. The code works the same until the input stream is accepted but it arrives as empty. There is not even the method/verb.

Comment: I think I'd need to see the code to help you further, I really have no idea what it could be tbh :/

Comment: @MissSkooterstandswPalestine I added the relevant codes

Comment: "There is not even the method/verb". That's not possible. HTTP requests *always* have a method, it's an essential part of the spec. So if you're getting `null`, there's a problem in your code. Not in the request itself.

Comment: @Jorn You are not wrong, but you can see my code, the inputStream is assigned empty (not null) when assigned from the socket. Is it possible that serverSocket.accept() returns anything other than an HTTP request (although Postman sends that) so the inputStream cannot be assigned? I have read the ServerSocket documentation but couldn't identify anything related to this. And also if there is a problem in my code, how is the browser request processed? There is now switch case, both requests are received the same way.

Comment: Those are good questions. You should use a debugger to try and find the answers.

Answer (score 0):

Just wanted to say I have the same issue, when working with Sockets first request from postman is always empty, second one is the same one the browser would have sent.

If you send the same request from browser it works.

My guess is that Postman tries to check if server is accessible with empty request that causes this when working with sockets.

Workaround in my case was to "swallow" the first exception that basically doesn't have any attributes and would cause NPE:

```java
while (true) {
    ServerSocket server = new ServerSocket(8080);
    Socket acceptedConnection = server.accept(); // accept is a blocking call
    HttpRequest request 
 = HttpRequest.valueOf(acceptedConnection.getInputStream());

    String path;
    try {
        path = request.getUrl().getSegments()[0];
    } catch (NullPointerException e) {
        // Postman's first NPE creating request handler
        return new HttpResponse();
    }
}
```

Because it is in a loop (like a server should be) returning an empty response for the first "check" call of postman solves the problem. You won't have this issue if you try with anything else like curl or browser